# Can i play installed games on xbox 360 without cd'

Tags: xbox-360

My xbox only reads original discs it's pal region and i want to know if it's possible somehow to play installed games without discs

Answer (score 2):

No. "Installing" games to the hard drive does not allow the console to play the game without the disc in the drive.

However, you can buy download versions of many (most?) games from the Xbox Live Marketplace, which you can play without needing to bother with discs.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you flash the hard drive, and other modifications. There is no way to play games installed from disc without the disc.

Comment: Unless you **"flash the hard drive"**? What does that mean? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Flash the hdd means you change the firmware on the hdd to circumvent M$ security measures. This voids warrenties, is technically illegal, and may result in being banned from Xbox live. Then again you may not get banned and then you can play burned games and games from a 2 tb external hdd. Just google flash xbox hdd and jtag Xbox hdd

Comment: *sigh* Look, my point is, you must pretend I know nothing as the Answer'er. You should add that information to your answer, not only will it look more professional, but the chances will be raised in getting upvoted/accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry new to this but I actively decided to not tell you to break the law as I am sure That constitutes conspiracy.

Comment: Well, it isn't breaking the law by explaining it. It's breaking the law **to do** it. It's good of you to be cautious of these risks though.

Comment: Advising you to though... to be honest im not sure either conspiracy or promoting a criminal act. I did tell you its possible. And did tell you the legality issues so who know but a lawyer. Good luck.

Comment: You too with your answer. :P